# Heroku+BItbucket deploy: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind hint: its remote counterpart

Tags: heroku, bitbucket, bitbucket-pipelines, heroku-cli

I am now working on a website. I use heroku to run my server and use bitbucket as the version control tool. I setup a pipeline to deploy directly from bitbucket to heroku. But I keep getting an error like:

```
+ git push https://heroku:$HEROKU_API_KEY@git.heroku.com/$HEROKU_APP_NAME.git HEAD
```

`To https://heroku:57eb7889-7395-4a7e-bd95-1312a40b30d1@git.heroku.com/hidden-ocean-90048.git
 ! [rejected]        HEAD -> master (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://heroku:57eb7889-7395-4a7e-bd95-1312a40b30d1@git.heroku.com/hidden-ocean-90048.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
hint: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g.
hint: 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.`

I tried git pull and git pull -f but it doesn't work. Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

You can push with -f like the below:

```
git push -f https://heroku:$HEROKU_API_KEY@git.heroku.com/$HEROKU_APP_NAME.git HEAD
```

Comment: How would you do when you use `subtree` for deploying e.g. `git subtree push --prefix folder_name heroku master` where the `-f` flag does not work?

Comment: @martin36 I didn't use with subtree before so I don't know how does it work.